# How to get access Spinners which i create in main activity in onCreate Method

Tags: java, android, android-spinner

When I try to make the button work dynamically and when the button is clicked I create 2 spinners and text views. I don't care about text but, I need to get all spinners data when calculate button clicked but with my way of thinking didn't work.

I need to know how can I store my spinners when I create it to restore it on click of calculate button.

This is the image of my app when the app is running it looks like this:

[image: this is image to my app when app running look like this]

Second image is when I add more records of 2 spinners and textView:

[image: Spinners added here]

Hope someone help me ..
Thanks in advance.

Main Activity Code:

```
package com.example.pc.gpacalculator;

import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.os.Build;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TableRow;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    ArrayList<String> list;
    static int count=1;
    ArrayList<Spinner>gradeSpinners;
    ArrayList<Spinner>creditSpinners;
    String array2[];
    String array[];
    Button button;

    // importnat two array to calculate your gpa
    // ast5dmo dol b2a wa7ed le elsa3at we wa7ed le grade a aw b we hkza we fe shwyt 7agat momkn ttdaf bokra b2a
    ArrayList<String> hoursArray;
    ArrayList<String> gradesArray;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        //intilaize our arrays

        hoursArray=new ArrayList<>();
        gradesArray=new ArrayList<>();

        array2=getResources().getStringArray(R.array.credit);
        array=getResources().getStringArray(R.array.grades);

        Spinner s1=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.creditSpinner1);
        Spinner s2=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.gradeSpinner1);

        final ArrayAdapter<String> gradeAdapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,array);
        final ArrayAdapter<String> creditAdapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,array2);

        s1.setAdapter(creditAdapter);
        s2.setAdapter(gradeAdapter);

        creditSpinners=new ArrayList<>();
        gradeSpinners=new ArrayList<>();

        creditSpinners.add(s1);
        gradeSpinners.add(s2);

        Button b=(Button) findViewById(R.id.add);
        b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                count++;
                LinearLayout linear=(LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.list);
                LinearLayout linearLayout=new LinearLayout(MainActivity.this);
                linearLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
                linearLayout.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));


                String Text="Class"+ " "+count;
                TextView textView=new TextView(MainActivity.this);
                textView.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(0, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,1f));
                textView.setText(Text);
                textView.setTextAppearance(MainActivity.this,android.R.style.TextAppearance_Material_Widget_ActionBar_Title);
                textView.setPadding(0,16,0,0);

                Spinner spinner = new Spinner(MainActivity.this);
                ArrayAdapter<String> spinerAdapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,array);
                spinner.setAdapter(spinerAdapter);
                spinner.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(0, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,1f));


                Spinner spinner2 = new Spinner(MainActivity.this);
                ArrayAdapter<String> spinerAdapter2=new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,array2);
                spinner2.setAdapter(spinerAdapter2);
                spinner2.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(0, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,1f));

                creditSpinners.add(spinner);
                gradeSpinners.add(spinner2);

                linearLayout.addView(textView);
                linearLayout.addView(spinner2);
                linearLayout.addView(spinner);
                linear.addView(linearLayout);

            }
        });

        button=(Button)findViewById(R.id.calculate);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                int total=0;
                for(int i=0;i<creditSpinners.size();i++)
                {
                    int value;
                    hoursArray.add(creditSpinners.get(i).getSelectedItem().toString());
                    gradesArray.add(gradeSpinners.get(i).getSelectedItem().toString());
                    value=Integer.valueOf(creditSpinners.get(i).getSelectedItem().toString());
                    // here total after getting Spinner one date exception appear NumberFormat beucase Spinners whcih i add dynamic has error 
                    total+=value;
                }
                button.setText(""+total);
            }
        });

    }
}
```

main_activtiy.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="20dp"
    tools:context="com.example.pc.gpacalculator.MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Class"
            android:textAllCaps="false" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Credit"
            android:textAllCaps="false" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Grade"
            android:textAllCaps="false" />


    </LinearLayout>

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/list"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Title"
                    android:text="Class 1"
                    android:id="@+id/textView2"
                    android:layout_weight="1" />

                <Spinner
                    android:id="@+id/creditSpinner1"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    />

                <Spinner
                    android:id="@+id/gradeSpinner1"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                     />

            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/add"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Add New Recored"
        android:textAllCaps="false" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/calculate"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Calculate"
        android:textAllCaps="false" />
</LinearLayout>
```

strings.xml

```
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">GPA Calculator</string>

    <string name="prompt">Choose Grade</string>
    <string name="prompt2">Choose Credit</string>
    <string-array name="grades">
        <item>Choose</item>
        <item>A</item>
        <item>B</item>
        <item>C</item>
        <item>D</item>
        <item>F</item>
    </string-array>
    <string-array name="credit">
        <item>Choose</item>
        <item>1</item>
        <item>2</item>
        <item>3</item>
        <item>4</item>
    </string-array>
</resources>
```

Comment: Tried your code and found that you have put the wrong spinners to the arrays. It should be, "creditSpinners.add(spinner2); gradeSpinners.add(spinner);"

Comment: yes i found it too .. thanks @I_A_Mok